# How to disable outputting variables inside Octave function

Tags: matlab, octave

I wrote my own function for Octave, but unfortunately aside of the final result value, the variable "result" is written to console on every change, which is an unwanted behavior.

```
>> a1 = [160 60]
a1 =

   160    60

>> entr = my_entropy({a1}, false)
result =  0.84535
entr =  0.84535
```

Should be

```
>> a1 = [160 60]
a1 =

   160    60

>> entr = my_entropy({a1}, false)
entr =  0.84535
```

I don't get the idea of ~ and it don't work, at least when I tried.
Code is as follows:

```
# The main difference between MATLAB bundled entropy function
# and this custom function is that they use a transformation to uint8
# and the bundled entropy() function is used mostly for signal processing
# while I simply use a straightforward solution usefull e.g. for learning trees

function f = my_entropy(data, weighted)
  # function accepts only cell arrays;
  # weighted tells whether return one weighed average entropy
  # or return a vector of entropies per bucket
  # moreover, I find vectors as the only representation of "buckets"
  # in other words, vector = bucket (leaf of decision tree)
  if nargin < 2
    weighted = true;
  end;

  rows = @(x) size(x,1);
  cols = @(x) size(x,2);

  if weighted
    result = 0;
  else
    result = [];
  end;

  for r = 1:rows(data)

    for c = 1:cols(data) # in most cases this will be 1:1

      omega = sum(data{r,c});
      epsilon = 0;

      for b = 1:cols(data{r,c})
        epsilon = epsilon + ( (data{r,c}(b) / omega) * (log2(data{r,c}(b) / omega)) );
      end;

      if (-epsilon == 0) entropy = 0; else entropy = -epsilon; end;

      if weighted
        result = result + entropy
      else
        result = [result entropy]
      end;

    end;

  end;

  f = result;

end;

# test cases

cell1 = { [16];[16];[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2];[12];[16] }
cell2 = { [16],[12];[16],[2];[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2],[8 8];[12],[8 8];[16],[8 8] }
cell3 = { [16],[3 3];[16],[2];[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2],[2 2];[12],[2];[16],[2] }

# end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you should end lines 39 and 41 with semicolon `;`.

Lines finishing in semicolon aren't shown in stdout.

Answer (score 3):

Add `;` after `result = result + entropy` and `result = [result entropy]` in your code, or in general after any assignment that you don't want printed on screen.

---

If for some reason you can't modify the function, you can use [`evalc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) to prevent unwanted output (at least in Matlab). Note that the output in this case is obtained in `char` form:

> `T = evalc(expression)` is the same as `eval(expression)` except that anything that would normally be written to the command window, except for error messages, is captured and returned in the character array `T` (lines in `T` are separated by `\n` characters).

As with any `eval` variant, this approach should be avoided if possible:

```
entr = evalc('my_entropy({a1}, false)');
```